# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app.publication' doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

im new to symfony and i have a little problem .
I created a db called theFeed and an entity called publication with doctrine and i added two fields on phpmyadmine but when i wanted to show these an error pops up saying the table doesn't exist...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

thx for your help !

I think the error comes from a search on the app base and not theFeed

Comment: Can you show us your doctrine.yaml/config.yaml with your database configuration

Comment: Error is about `'app.publication'`, it mean Doctrine looks on `app` database, I think you should clear your cache if you changed your `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: how did you created your entity? could you please provide your publication.php

Comment: Show your entity, and did you do a migration to your database ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to create the entity by `make:entity` command. [Make entity docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class), it's de better way to create a new entity or add fields if you are new in symfony.

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

After that, run migrations, and let met know if it works for you.

Comment: op issue is not creating an entity but which database is used by doctrine

Comment: may be the table is not created because he doesn't created the entity correctly